# SSRS not pulling latest column from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that pulls the latest date from a table. When I run that stored procedure, it pulls exactly what I am looking for.

The issue I am having is when I use the stored procedure in my SSRS report, it pulls the second latest date from the table.

In my stored procedure, I have 2 variables, `@StartTime` and `@Endtime`. When I have those variables as my parameters in SSRS for the report that is suppose to pull the correct times, those SSRS parameters are pulling the second latest date instead of the most recent like the stored procedure does correctly in the first place.

I've already tried refreshing the fields in the SSRS report and that did not work.

Is it possible that SSRS has messed up the times in a way? I can't think of any other reasons why SSRS would display the wrong time and the stored procedure would...

Comment: Is this while developing in VS or after deploying? It could be as simple as you looking at cached data. Change the parameters to a different value and then back to what you want.. it forces a cache refresh..

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Harry. That did force the cache refresh. Would it help if I said these variables StartTime and EndTime are being pushed as parameters to a sub-report?

Comment: What .data file @Dale Burrell ?

Comment: I am on a server using Report Builder so I don't know if that would work.

Comment: if you are just developing..  the subreport data will be cached as well. the .data file is the cache file that you can find in the project. you can delete the .data file to force a refresh or change parameters to force a refresh. This is only an "issue" while developing.. once deployed to server, it will not cache the data.. unless you want it to and set report caching options.